# How do I add a key to Flask's 'session' dictionary that would be available throughout the run of a program?

Tags: python, session, dictionary, flask, jinja2

The *Flask* context variable - *session* - is useful for passing values around in a program(especially between Flask and *Jinja2* in my case). How do I add a key to this dictionary at the start of my program (even before any route or view function is accessed) so I can use it throughout the lifetime of the program?

For instance I wish to add a user dict to this variable like so:

```
session['user'] = {}
```

and update (by adding or removing keys) with values during the program run.

Comment: Why are you using the session to pass stuff to Jinja rather than passing things through `render_template` or context processors? Also, the session is probably not what you want for the user. You probably want to attach the user to `g` in a `before_request` handler.

Comment: I'm using session so I have global access to the values I need. Using the render_template in my opinion implies I'll be passing so many parameters and then I'll have to do that with even more view functions (I'm not sure, but would that be good practice?) Also, thanks for the heads up about 'g'.

Comment: Putting everything in the session means you're passing it back and forth between the browser on every request just to get them into your templates. Look into context processors.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thanks.